# c# ListBox Issue

Tags: c#, listbox

Is it possible Implement Drag and drop elements within the ListBox to change their order,

Say there are 10 elements in list box,I should be able to drag the first element and drop at 4th place.

Comment: This question has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805165/reorder-a-winforms-listbox-using-drag-and-drop

Answer (score 0):

Here's how someone else has done this:

[Drag-and-Drop ListBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/DragDropListBox.aspx)