# User sortable list control

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to give to a windows form user (C# 4.0 application) a way to act on a control showing a list containing several items. What is needed is to give to the user a way to select an item and then to move it upside or downside because changing the order. A possible solution is in the following image that shows a possible implementation using a couple of buttons (labeled + and -) to change a sort key value for each element then giving the reorder responsibility to an  override of the alphabetical  sort provided by a ListBox control. The change must persists until form disposal

[image: A possible sortable list]

I am wondering if there is a better or simpler way to get the same result; maybe there is some control featuring capabilities that I am unaware of. Thanks

Comment: Do you want the user defined order to be persisted?

Comment: Take a look at [Reorder a winforms listbox using drag and drop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805165/reorder-a-winforms-listbox-using-drag-and-drop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no builtin control for this. The solution you suggest can easily be implemented using the `Remove` and `Insert` methods for the `ListBox.Items` collection.

Another solution could be to allow the user to drag & drop the items. Look at CodeCaster's link in the comments to your question.